# Why does the android image stop changing after two times?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

silly noob question, but hope someone is kind enough to help!
I'm trying to alter an image between two source as a button is pressed. two images are stored in drawable called pic1 and pic2. but running the code results in the picture changing twice and then not changing further. Can someone explain?

Here is the code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button changeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChange);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        final Drawable current = image.getDrawable(); //this is pic1
        changeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(image.getDrawable()==current) //if pic1
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
                else image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't update the current and variable are final .
In java you cannot change final variable [see here](http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword).
Just declare those variable default or public and update the current variable in the onClick method

```
Button changeBtn;
ImageView image;
Drawable current;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    changeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChange);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    current = image.getDrawable(); //this is pic1
    changeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(image.getDrawable()==current) //if pic1
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
            else image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    current = image.getDrawable(); //this will update the current , you have to update the current because it change in the if/else condition

        }
    });
```

try it and let me know what happens